# csv stream for machine learning algorithms

Tags: python, algorithm, csv, machine-learning, data-science

I have a big CSV file (around 5GB).
I am trying to read line by line the whole file and try to apply the most typikal algorithms (SVM, Naive Bayes, Linear Regression, etc).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import csv

i_f = open('top2Mmm.csv', 'r' )
reader = csv.reader( i_f, delimiter = ';' )
for row in reader:
print("Fila  ->", row)
```

I have just managed to read the CSV but I don´t know how to take each row and build a model.
I am starting with a smaller file to speed up with the process but I dont know how to make this process work properly.
Any clue or tip?

Comment: I am suggesting to try `pandas` with `read_csv` method.

Comment: Unfortunately, its not a simple task. Most ML estimators require the whole data to be present at once to learn. If you want to do it in smaller batches, you need to consider those ML algorithms that support it. Read more about "Online transfer learning", "Out-of-core learning", "Incremental learning" etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Pandas Dataframe object to load the CSV, and manipulate the data that way.

You can also iterate through the dataframe if needed.

```
df = pd.read_csv('top2Mmm.csv', sep=';')
for index, row in train.iterrows():
    print(row['fieldName'])
```

Comment: it does not work for that amount of data I tryied to use this script but it overload my ram...also my method make the same situation and idk how to solve this kind of problems. I guess I need to read line by line all the dataset and process line by line in real time execution and try to apply all the algorithms

Answer (score 0):

Separate your data(row) into features(X) and labels(y). Then you can apply them to, for instance, SVM.

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
clf = SVC()
clf.fit(X, y)
```

[sklearn.svm reference](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html)